# change phone properties so I can download an item from Google play?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod

I have a Huawei u8160(A.K.A Vodafone 858 Smart) which had an original Froyo ROM , Now it's upgraded to CyanogenMod7.2(Gingerbread) and even after upgrading Google play apps are the same exactly.

I was wondering if I can change the properties of my phone so that Google play would understand that I'm running Gingerbread?

Comment: Which apps are you expecting to have new versions?

Comment: i don't know but goomanager before and after upgrading wasn't compatible but after i installed it manually and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apps will not just change when your version changes. All Apps have a minimum API Version which is required to use the App. So if your apps all have a minimum API version of e.g. Froyo and there is no special version for gingerbread all will stay the same.

The Properties of the android version cannot be changed, only if you compile your own system and write a different version number in there. But this will not solve the problem of the API Versions: If you Fake an Android 4.0.3 with 2.3.6 Real System Version, some Apps will probably not run because they need to have API Version 15 and not 8.

Comment: when i compile an api 10 app using eclipse it runs normally while Froyo's API is 8

Comment: as long as you dont use API Calls which are only in 10 it will work of course

Comment: here's something: an app called photo art google play on pc tells me "not compatible" while it's already installed it and google play phone says it's compatible so that's what i want to do i want to update the information on their site

Comment: okay i dont see any chance to change it... when your google play store on PC does not get the correct information from the phone i hardly belive its not possible at all to push it manually... the market protocol was sometime ago reverse engienered but still then alot changed and i dont know if someone checked it out again... can you install still software from the PC market?

Comment: maybe you can just tell the support: https://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/request.py?contact_type=contact_policy&policy=apps but the problem will be that you are not using a google android version...

Comment: I'm able to install any app that was compatible with the old version of my phone that was froyo